# SFML removing elements from vector

Tags: c++, vector, sfml, collision, erase

Hello I have a problem with vectors I have double loop where I erase elements from both vectors and I have a problem when I remove element from first loop's vector it is showing the error "vector too long". I had similar problem in my last project but this time I can't to solve it the same way I did last time. The error is showing after last bullet hit the wall.

collision func

```
void Game::BulletHit(int j, std::vector <Bullet>& team, std::vector <Squares>& square, 
std::vector <Squares>& square2)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < bulletTeam1.size(); i++)
    {    
        if(team[i].bullet.getGlobalBounds().intersects(square[j].square.getGlobalBounds()))
        {
            int x = square[j].square.getPosition().x;
            int y = square[j].square.getPosition().y;
            //sf::Color color = square[j].square.getFillColor();
            square.erase(square.begin() + j);
            Squares1.square.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
            Squares1.square.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(x, y));
            square2.push_back(Squares1);
            team.erase(team.begin() + i);
            std::cout << "collison  " << team.size() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

code where i use it

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < team1.size(); i++)
{
    BulletHit(i, bulletTeam2, team1, team2);
    //BulletHit(i, bulletTeam3, team1, team3);
    //BulletHit(i, bulletTeam4, team1, team4);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we have enough information to fully understand your problem.

One thing that I can point out and you maybe didn't catch is, that calling `square.erase(square.begin() + j);` will remove the j-th element from the square vector. But then you continue to run the inner loop, thus in the next iteration, you'll *again* remove the j-th element. This will run until there are fewer than j elements in the vector and then crash or the inner loop exits early. Either way, I believe this may not be the intended goal here and you may want to remove the j-th element outside the inner loop, so that the j-th element is only removed once.